# How to update a record using updateAttributes with sequelize.js and node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a database table called `adresses` where I want to update any field by submitting a form.

so, lets say I want to update the field `name`:

I have the HTML input field:

```
<input type="text" name="name" />
```

Then I have this method in Node.js:

```
var changeName = function(cb){

    db.addresses.find({where : {id: '21' }})
        .success(function(name){

            db.addresses.updateAttributes({name: req.body.name})
            .success(function(){  cb(null)  })
            .error(cb);
        })
        .error(cb);             
}
```

When I submit the form, nothing happens and I dont get an error. What am I doing wrong here?

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: does the success function fire?

Comment: hmm it doesnt seem like it fires... how can I find out?

Comment: try with simple `alert('I'm there!');`

Comment: no, nothing happens.. :-s

Comment: where did you put the alert? Success of the find or success of the updateAttributes?

Comment: better use console.log("it's work!") - it's better practice. use alert only if you need quick checking of small piece of code)

Comment: @faby I put the alert (and console.log()) inside the success of find and updateAttributes

Comment: which is the type of your Id column?

Comment: if it is an Int you should use `find({where : {id: 21 }})` (if it solve your problem I'll add an answer)

Comment: Hmm no, unfortunately this doesnt work... i'm starting to believe the error is somewhere else :-s

Comment: You are calling `updateAttributes` on the model, you need to call it on the instance returned from `find`, looks like the undefined method error is getting swallowed somewhere though.